# Can we add custom javascript and css to Alfresco community edition?

Tags: javascript, html, alfresco, alfresco-share

I wish to add external javascript and css files to Alfresco community edition.

For eg. Can I add Bootstrap library(javascript & css) ? If so where do I add it?

Also while editing a wiki page, I see an option to view and modify the source code in 'View menu'. I punch in html there and it works fine. But it doesn't have a place-holder to add javascript and css.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To include your javascript in classpath of alfresco share you could do following entry in your share-config-custom.xml

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocLibCustom" replace="true">

    <dependencies>
        <js src="/js/custom-script.js" />
        <css src="/css/custom-style.csss" />
    </dependencies>

</config>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: what is the root location of it